# Excel Formula for removing leading 1 on phone number if present

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, formula

I am needing to create a formula that removes the leading 1 from a 11 digit phone number as shown below.

I would also like the formula to exclude any 10 numbers that doesn't have a leading 1.

I am trying to have my list all the same with just 10 digits.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this if you are sure the value are clean and no spaces and dash

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=11, RIGHT(A1,10),A1)
```

Comment: You rock! The below formula worked perfectly. The 11 digit number had no dashes or spaces. :)
=IF(LEN(A1)=11, RIGHT(A1,10),A1)

Answer (score 2):

Use this simple formula:

```
=--Right(E2,10)
```

The Right() Function turns it into text so the `--` turns it back to a number.

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
=IFERROR(--TEXT(--RIGHT(E2, 10), "[>1999999999]0000000000;;;"), "")
```

Comment: The [RIGHT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RIGHT-RIGHTB-functions-240267EE-9AFA-4639-A02B-F19E1786CF2F) returns the ten-right-most digits regardless of what the 11th digit is or even if there isn't an 11th digit. The `"[>1999999999]0000000000;;;"` format mask only produces a ten-digit number if the first digit starts with at least a **2**; nothing if it starts with a 1 or is a nine-or-less digit number.

Comment: And we look for the 2 because US Area codes start with 201 and go up.  I see, It is a way to check if the data is valid.